# Secured/encrypted PDF: iOS 4.3 displays blank pages

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf, encryption

In a web application we provide some documents as PDF files that can be downloaded or emailed. It nicely works with desktop operating systems where the PDF files are usually viewed with Adobe Reader. However, some iPhones and iPads only display blank pages both when opening the file from Safari or the email app.

We've tried to isolate the problem and it looks as if the following factors are relevant:

- iPhones with iOS 4.2 can display the PDF files, iPhones and iPads with iOS 4.3 cannot.
- It only affects secured/encrypted files.

We use PDF encryption to set permissions on the files in order to prevent modification, comments etc. Viewing and printing the files is allowed and doesn't require a password.

The PDF files are generated from a Postscript file with Ghostscript and the following options:

```
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPermissions#-3900 -dEncryptionR#3 -sOwnerPassword#123456
```

Has anybody experienced the same problems? Did Apple change something with iOS 4.3? Are there any other encryption settings that could work?

Comment: Have you made a thorough check of the iOS 4.3 documentation?  In particular the "What's changed" section, or its equivalent.  Also check the bug list to see if you are hitting a known problem.

Comment: I have read the release documention for iOS 4.3 and haven't found anything yet. But I don't know of any bug list that is accessible to registered developers (or to the public). Do you know where to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please try adding :

> -dKeyLength#128

to your postscript generation. I had a similar problem (with safari desktop) and that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to help. However, the permission to print has now been reduced to low quality. So I'll have to look into this and I'll need to do tests on more devices. I'll keep you posted...

Comment: I've soloved the resolution settings with `-dPermissions#-1852`. The testing will take more time.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works only all devices we have tested.